# Put option valuation

Tags: finance, financial-economics

Does a European put have different fair values at time 0 in long and short position? If so, could you explain to my why? Instinctively, I think the answer is that there is no difference, since evaluating options at fair value implies perfect economy with no arbitrage opportunity.

Comment: At time 0 meaning at expiry?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are differences.  Option contracts are like certificates of deposit and not like stocks or bonds.  They are only created when another party agrees to create them, which in practice requires a market maker.  The market maker, being a profit seeking firm, will require a bid-ask spread.  This spread guarantees the laws of probability hold because it fulfills the requirements of de Finetti's Coherence Principle.  The coherence principle is a weaker claim than the no arbitrage principle.  The coherence principle implies that the bookie cannot be gamed, but the players can be gamed by the bookie.  The no arbitrage is one directional.

If you assume no market maker, then you violate the most basic principles of economics.  It may make for simpler math, but there is no universe in which it would be a valid model.

See https://ssrn.com/abstract=2653255 for a discussion of this.